# iOS 9 error while running Worklight 6.1 Application

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

We have tried to run WL 6.1 Fix Pack FP02 app on iOS 9 and got the following error in main.m file:

```
‘Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch’
The exception is thrown on this line of main.m:
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, appClass, @”MyAppDelegate”);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the stack trace from xcode 7 :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x047e0a94 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0429fe02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x047e092a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 138
    3   Foundation                          0x00f0e3e6 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 118
    4   UIKit                               0x012b3568 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 3674
    5   UIKit                               0x012d6905 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3171 + 68
    6   UIKit                               0x012afbae -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 163
    7   FrontBoardServices                  0x07c1cccc __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    8   FrontBoardServices                  0x07c1c7a3 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    9   FrontBoardServices                  0x07c3a1cb -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x07c3a602 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 52
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x07c398fe FBSSerialQueueRunLoopSourceHandler + 33
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x046fae7f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x046f0b0b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 523
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x046eff28 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x046ef866 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x046ef67b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    17  UIKit                               0x012af497 -[UIApplication _run] + 540
    18  UIKit                               0x012b4cc1 UIApplicationMain + 160
    19  MYAPP                               0x00100f5d main + 157
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x04c8ba21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Can you provide actual code that can be run and debugged? Provide your Xcode project.

Comment: No, I can't. I will try to run hello world app on the same configuration and will provide you the source code if it gives me the same error.

Comment: @IdanAdar You can download the code that produces the same error from below link : https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6F30ECBBDD7BA427!29589&authkey=!APV0iFDbFYlzKgc&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to upgrade your development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

- Tested with the provided Hello World project - failing
- Tested with the latest available iFix - working

Please upgrade.

---

Without proper example that can be debugged it is difficult to answer, but it should be noted that for applications compiled with Xcode 7 to correctly function you need to make sure, at minimum, to make the following tweaks:

1. Disable Bitcode, as it is currently not supported.
2. Correctly define ATS (either allow all addresses, or correctly setup the client application with HTTPS, and the server with TLS 1.2 support).

Read more about ATS and Bitcode, here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/

See if that resolves this issue. If not, you must provide an application with reproduction steps.

You should also note that 6.1 Fix Pack 2 is extremely old and you should, as an IBM customer, login to IBM Fix Central and download the latest available iFix (for Studio and Server) and upgrade. This latest iFix also contains iOS 9 related fixes, so it is advised to test with it first, in addition to the above required changes for applications compiled in Xcode 7.

From the provided example project, you are not even using Fix Pack 2, but 1. Even older...

Comment: I have downloaded Fix Pack 2 Enterprise Version from below location but it is showing 6.1.0.1 in Eclipse. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24038244

Comment: Again, as I wrote, I asked you to download *the latest iFix from IBM Fix Central*, which is **newer** than Fix Pack 2. Download the latest. Latest.

Answer (score 0):

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch’

This error is caused when there is no view controller for the app to go to after the launch. This could be because you have not created one yet because you started with an empty application, you deleted the view controller, or it might be you deleted the entrance point to the main view controller.